# Do unused methods slow down classes in Python?

Tags: python, performance, class

I'm wondering if having many methods could ever significantly slow down the implementation of a Python class.
Let's say we have two classes:

```
class FirstClass():

    def __init__(x1, x2, ..., xN)
        * init code *
    method1(self):
        * Method 1 code *

class SecondClass():

    def __init__(x1, x2, ..., xN)
        * the same init code *
    method2(self):
        * Method 1 code *
    method3(self):
        * Method 2 code *
    ...
    method100(self):
        * Method 100 code *
```

If I create many variables of **SecondClass**, will having these extra methods create much of a performance hit in terms of speed or memory size compared to **FirstClass**? Is this ever something worth worrying about?

Obviously it depends on what is in init, but for argument sake let's say we have some light weight code.

Comment: Go nuts -- not an issue. Python will handle as many methods as you have the patience to type. Someone might give you a full explanation, or point you to one already on this web site, but that's the bottom line.

Comment: Well, The idea is not about performance. Python can read GBs of data.
It's about readability. I think you can write some argument dependant ccode for `method100(self)` like `method(self, n)` where if n is 100 you can run method 2 code.